# run docker-compose up -d but I conflict error of ruby version

Tags: ruby, docker

I installed repository from books 
here is repository url

```
git clone https://github.com/efkbook/blog-sample
```

and I conflict error of ruby version
how Can I solve this?

```
docker-compose up -d
```

error message:

```
Step 5/7 : RUN /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-elasticsearch fluent-plugin-record-reformer
 ---> Running in 6f05fb399ffe
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed msgpack-1.3.3
Successfully installed serverengine-2.2.1
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fluent-plugin-elasticsearch:
    fluentd requires Ruby version >= 2.4.
Successfully installed strptime-0.2.3
Successfully installed fluent-plugin-record-reformer-0.9.1
Parsing documentation for fluent-plugin-record-reformer-0.9.1
Installing ri documentation for fluent-plugin-record-reformer-0.9.1
Done installing documentation for fluent-plugin-record-reformer after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
ERROR: Service 'fluentd' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-elasticsearch fluent-plugin-record-reformer' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: thanks for editing of my question

Comment: It's nothing. I'm investigating your problem now.

Comment: It seems there's either no Ruby installed in the docker image, or the Ruby version is too low. Can you add `RUN ruby --version` before the line `RUN /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-elasticsearch fluent-plugin-record-reformer
` in the file `Dockerfile-fluentd` and try again?

Comment: Ok I will try it

Comment: I got error message

Comment: Step 5/8 : RUN ruby --version
 ---> Running in 41aebda99bb6
/bin/sh: 1: ruby: not found
ERROR: Service 'fluentd' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ruby --version' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: Oh I see I write ```FROM ruby:2.4.0``` in Dockerfile-fluentd

Comment: I write ```RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y ruby``` In Dockerfile-fluentd right now

Comment: It may not work because the version of Ruby in the Debian package manager is 2.1.5, which is too low. I can't find a way to install 2.4 or above in Debian 8 (Jessie), but the Ruby in Debian 10 (buster) is 2.5. So change the first line in `Dockerfile-fluentd` to `FROM debian:buster` should work.

Comment: Oh I got new error message ***Step 6/8 : RUN /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-elasticsearch fluent-plugin-record-reformer
 ---> Running in d2978c2772a9
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem: not found***

Comment: So I write ***RUN mkdir -p /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem*** too

Comment: At this point, you may want to report a bug to the author of efkbook/blog-sample. The Dockerfile-fluentd is 2 years old.

Comment: Yeah I got it but I got new error ***/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem: Permission denied
ERROR: Service 'fluentd' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-elasticsearch fluent-plugin-record-reformer' returned a non-zero code: 126***

Comment: I don't know how to sudo command in docker file

Comment: Most of the time you don't need sudo because the default user when building docker images is root. If you don't explicitly change user, the default user is also root when you run a container.